# Google Calendar API Errors

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have been receiving errors using the Google Calendar API for server to server functions and I cannot find any documentation on the errors.

Here are some of the Errors I received. This one is from testing the PHP Script: "Invalid Invocation."

Here is the PHP Code which is a near perfect copy of what is on Google, the directories are slightly modified so that they point to the proper locations on the server:

```
    <?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/autoload.php';

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '~/.google-api-php-client/src');
define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/calendar-php-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
  Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY)
));

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
  throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient() {
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
  $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
  $client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
  $client->setAccessType('offline');

  // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
  $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
  if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
    $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
  } else {
    // Request authorization from the user.
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
    print 'Enter verification code: ';
    $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
    $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);

    // Store the credentials to disk.
    if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
      mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
    printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
  }
  $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

  // Refresh the token if it's expired.
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
  }
  return $client;
}

/**
 * Expands the home directory alias '~' to the full path.
 * @param string $path the path to expand.
 * @return string the expanded path.
 */
function expandHomeDirectory($path) {
  $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
  if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
    $homeDirectory = getenv('HOMEDRIVE') . getenv('HOMEPATH');
  }
  return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
}

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

// Print the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
$calendarId = 'primary';
$optParams = array(
  'maxResults' => 10,
  'orderBy' => 'startTime',
  'singleEvents' => TRUE,
  'timeMin' => date('c'),
);
$results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);

if (count($results->getItems()) == 0) {
  print "No upcoming events found.\n";
} else {
  print "Upcoming events:\n";
  foreach ($results->getItems() as $event) {
    $start = $event->start->dateTime;
    if (empty($start)) {
      $start = $event->start->date;
    }
    printf("%s (%s)\n", $event->getSummary(), $start);
  }
}
```

This is the error I received testing as a regular RestApi adding the information into a URL and I added the API key in curly Brackets like so, key={API Key}, as shown on Google:

```
    {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "keyInvalid",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```

This one I removed the curly brackets from the url and treated it more like a traditional RestApi as shown, key=API Key:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
    "message": "The request did not specify any referer. Please ensure that the client is sending referer or use the API Console to remove the referer restrictions.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=293878597674"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The request did not specify any referer. Please ensure that the client is sending referer or use the API Console to remove the referer restrictions."
 }
}
```

And most everything else I have tried results in a blank screen that doesn't give me any useful data.

Comment: Checking the document about [Authorizing Requests to the Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth), Your application must use [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) to authorize requests. No other authorization protocols are supported. If your application uses [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/#google-sign-in), some aspects of authorization are handled for you. Double check if you have set the correct type and added any JavaScript origins, redirect URIs, or both. Hope this helps!

Comment: I am actually trying for a Service Account for Server to Server access so I can connect multiple different calendars to my CRM for different uses for each calendar.